# Not able to add url in Django router

Tags: django, django-views, url-routing

I am not able to add workers URL which is pointing to a method in views.py. In below urls.py configuration, I had created a DefaultRouter, and registered 6 URLs. First 5 are working good(They are Class Based Views), however the last URL(workers, which is method based view) is not working. This URL is not matched with any of the URLs listed in url.conf. Error message I am getting 'Using the URLconf defined in maidFactory.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:. . . . . . .The current URL, workers/, didn't match any of these.'

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'slots', views.SlotViewSet)
router.register(r'city', views.CityViewSet)
router.register(r'location',views.LocationViewSet,base_name='locationMy')
router.register(r'workers',views.WorkerViewSet,base_name='getWorkersBySlotAndLocation')

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
#url(r'^', include('maidFactory.api.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls')),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))]
```

My method based view is as follows:

```
def WorkerViewSet(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    #cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    cursor.execute("select p.wid,p.fname, a.description from workerProfile as p, workerAccount as a where a.isactive=1 and a.wid=p.wid")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return HttpResponse(row)
```

Comment: However, If I add workers in urlpatterns itself as below, it works:
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
        url(r'^workers/',views.WorkerViewSet),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls')),
        url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]

But I want to add it in DefaultRouter itself, so that going forward I can manage them.

Answer (score 0):

**Your `WorkerViewSet` is not a actual [DRF ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) but a Django function-based view returning Django HttpResponse.**

You should convert it to a proper DRF viewset and then register your router with this viewset.

Another option is to add this as a url in `urlpatterns` in your urls file and it should work perfectly.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^my/url/path/$', my_views.WorkerViewSet), # This will work
    ....
]
```